# Downloading file in node.js into user specified path

Tags: angularjs, node.js

i'm trying to download file using node.js and this is my code:

```
var file_url = req.body.filename;
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';
var options = {
    host: url.parse(file_url).host,
    port: 80,
    path: url.parse(file_url).pathname
};
var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
var file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name);  
http.get(options, function (resp) {
    resp.on('data', function (data) {
        file.write(data);
    }).on('end', function () {
        file.end();           
        console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);     


        delet(file_url);     
    });
});
```

here i'm giving DOWNLOAD_DIR manually so it is downloading to that

directory as it is localhost not a problem, but when i'm uploading this

code into server then the file should be downloaded to that particular

user's machine, so how to give path dynamically to DOWNLOAD_DIR variable

Comment: You cannot control the path where user prefers to download the file. You create writestream on your server, of course it works locally. But user sets the path using browser settings (f.e. in Chrome: Settings-Downloaded files).

Answer (score 0):

if the Downloads folder is in home directory (and you want to download in Downloads folder), then you can use

```
var path = require('path'); 
var file_url = req.body.filename;       
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads/');
var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
var file_path = path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR,file_name);
var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
```

PS: While dealing with paths and files, always use path module of nodejs to generate path.

Comment: how to show status about downloading.I am using angular.js as front-end

Comment: Can you please tell me in your case what exact path "process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE" returns?

Comment: @PriyankaPawar you don't exactly need process.env.HOME or process.env.USERPROFILE. You can give the path manually. HOME and USERPROFILE are just the environment variables. You can check the value of these variables by running "echo $HOME" on linux or "echo %USERPROFILE%" on windows. These variables are usually set to the home path of the user; "/Users/xyz" in case of linux, and "C:\Users\xyz" in case of windows.

Comment: Yes these variables works fine on localhost but I am asking what it returns from instance?

Comment: It will return whatever is the value of environment variables. If both HOME and USERPROFILE are not set to any value, then you will get an error; because you are passing undefined to path.join function.

Comment: In my case it returns "/home/ec2-user". How can client will have this folder on their machine? Check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/41100642/3992253

Comment: If you want the file to be downloaded from the client side, then you just need to stream the file from nodejs. You cannot write code in nodejs to download the file at client side. You have to stream the file via some endpoint (api), and then consume that api at the client side. Assuming that the client is browser in your case, you will write code in frontend Javascript to download the file on user's machine.