# Download AWS S3 file from EC2 instance using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to download file from Amazon S3 bucket from my Node.js hosted application.

```
var folderpath= process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE  // tried using os.homedir() also

var filename  =  'ABC.jpg';
var filepath = 'ABC';

 AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "XXX",
    secretAccessKey: "XXX",
    region: 'ap-southeast-1'
 });

  var DOWNLOAD_DIR = path.join(folderpath, 'Downloads/');

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var s3Params = {Bucket: filepath,Key: filename, };

    var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR+ filename);
    s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

This code works fine on localhost but does not work from instance because on instance folderpath returns "/home/ec2-user" instead of path of downloads folder of user machine i.e something like "C:\Users\name".

Please suggest me how can I download file to user's machine? How to get path of user's home directory from ec2 instance?

Thank you.

Comment: As a side note: it's a bad idea to keep your secretAccessKey in code. You should create IAM role and assign it to EC2 instance.

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you @Sergey Kovalev

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error? `folderpath` is a normal directory path on a Linux machine (it's `ec2-user`'s home directory). Did you make sure that the `/home/ec2-user/Downloads/` directory exists and the user has writing permissions to it?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors but I want User's downloads folder path. Why would I need permissions to writing in /home/ec2-user/../ ? How can other users will have ec2-user folder on their machine?

Comment: If you want the file to be downloaded from the client side, then you just need to stream the file from nodejs. You cannot write code in nodejs to download the file at client side. You have to stream the file via some endpoint (api), and then consume that api at the client side. Assuming that the client is browser in your case, you will write code in frontend Javascript to download the file on user's machine.

Comment: @manish thank you I will try this. If possible can you please provide me any useful link or code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use express to create http server and APIs. You can find numerous tutorials on get started with Express.js. After the initial setup of express.js is done, you can do something like this in node.js code:

```
AWS.config.update({
   accessKeyId: "XXX",
   secretAccessKey: "XXX",
   region: 'ap-southeast-1'
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  var filename = 'ABC.jpg';
  var filepath = 'ABC';
  var s3Params = {Bucket: filepath, Key: filename};
  var mimetype = 'video/quicktime'; // or whatever is the file type, you can use mime module to find type

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  // Here we are reading the file from S3, creating the read stream and piping it to the response.
  // I'm not sure if this would work or not, but that's what you need: Read from S3 as stream and pass as stream to response (using pipe(res)).
  s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
});
```

Once this is done, you can call this API `/download`, and then download the file on user's machine. Depending on the framework or library (or plain javascript) which you are using in front end, you can download the file using this `/download` api. Just google, how to download file using XYZ (framework).

Comment: It returns data of file means still I have write file in angular.js which probably leads to find path and provide to createWriteStream()

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts but I think singed url would be easy to use.